# Can't copy folder with files from external hard drive because of permissions?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, hard-drive, permission

I can't copy a folder (with files) from an external hard drive because of permissions problems. (You do not have permissions to the files in this folder.)

However, those files were created by me (on Snow Leopard - I'm on Lion right now). Is there any want to force or gain admin permissions on those files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiar with terminal you can use the following command;

```
sudo chown -R username directory
```

username: your username
directory: the folder in which the files you want to copy are located

PS Requires an administrator's password